# System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webmethods

First off, let me clarify the platforms we are using. We have an ASP.NET 2.0 app calling a web service which was created and is hosted on webMethods (now SoftwareAG) Integration Server 7.1.2.

The issue we are experiencing appears to occur every 10-20 minutes under a moderate volume of attempts.  The .NET app tries to call the web service and gets the "*System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled*" error message.  There are no errors logged on the Integration Server when this problem occurs.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a nasty one... and little information.

I think you will have to analyze with other tools...

Can it be that the request is stopped somewhere along the way?
Maybe you can try and follow the request with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

Comment: That can't hurt, I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Wireshark showed that we are getting TCP Checksum errors on some of our packets. Now we have to figure out why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Which logs have you checked on the Integration server and with log levels have you applied?
You could e.g. check if a HTTP connection could be established.